# UI blocked and longer load time without setTimeout()

Tags: angular

I have a component who in its `ngOnInit` subscribes to a `BehaviorSubject` in a service. The code sets the datasource for a `mat-table`:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.citizenService.citizens.subscribe((citizens: Citizen[]) => {
  console.log(citizens);
  if (citizens.length > 0) {
    citizens.forEach(citizen => {
      citizen.weekInterval = "Ikke nok";
      citizen.weeklyCare.forEach(wc => {
        if (wc.hospitalized) {
          Object.keys(wc).forEach(key => {
            if (key != "weeklyCareIdentifier" && key != "hospitalized") {
              wc[key] = null;
            }
          });
        }
      });
      this.citizenService.calculateCareChange(citizen, false);
    })
    let citizensWithAlerts: Citizen[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(citizens));
    for (let i = citizensWithAlerts.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
      if (!citizensWithAlerts[i].totalCare || !(citizensWithAlerts[i].totalCare >= this.citizenService.alertThreshold)) {
        citizensWithAlerts.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    citizensWithAlerts = citizensWithAlerts.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.totalCare < b.totalCare) return 1;
      if (a.totalCare > b.totalCare) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.citizenWithAlerts = citizensWithAlerts;
    this.citizensToPrint = citizensWithAlerts;
    this.tableDataSource.data = citizens;
  }
});
}
```

When the component is initialized, my application gets blocked for like 6 seconds, and then the component's view appears with the table populated with data. However, if I put all of the above code inside a `setTimeout(() => {**code**}, 0 );` the view is initialized instantly, and the table populated immediately after. The `setTimeout` somehow makes a difference of 6 seconds.

Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Also, the code was working fine when I instead of subscribing to a `BehaviorSubject` subscribed to an `Observable` created from an http call.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Quadratic Complexity: O(N²)

and then inside this 2d for loop you calculating some stuff

and then you sort.

try to use the ngAfterViewInit() {} with a timeout inside, this will make the difference.

also, initialize the table with an empty array.

Yout code can look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private _citizenService: SitizenService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableDataSource.data = new DataSource([]);
    this.getSitizens();
  }

  getSitizens() {
    this.citizenService.citizens.subscribe((citizens: Citizen[]) => {

      console.log(citizens);

      // add comments
      if (citizens.length > 0) {
        citizens.forEach(citizen => {
          citizen.weekInterval = "Ikke nok";
          citizen.weeklyCare.forEach(wc => {
            if (wc.hospitalized) {
              Object.keys(wc).forEach(key => {
                if (key != "weeklyCareIdentifier" && key != "hospitalized") {
                  wc[key] = null;
                }
              });
            }
          });
          this.citizenService.calculateCareChange(citizen, false);
        });

        // add comments
        let citizensWithAlerts: Citizen[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(citizens));
        for (let i = citizensWithAlerts.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
          if (!citizensWithAlerts[i].totalCare || !(citizensWithAlerts[i].totalCare >= this.citizenService.alertThreshold)) {
            citizensWithAlerts.splice(i, 1);
          }
        };

        // add comments
        citizensWithAlerts = citizensWithAlerts.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.totalCare < b.totalCare) return 1;
          if (a.totalCare > b.totalCare) return -1;
          return 0;
        });

        // add comments
        this.citizenWithAlerts = citizensWithAlerts;
        this.citizensToPrint = citizensWithAlerts;
        this.tableDataSource.data = citizens;
      }
    });
  }


}

class DataSource {
  constructor(private data: any[]){}
}
```